# Counting how often x occures per y and Visualize in R

Tags: r, count, histogram

I would like to count certain things in my dataset. I have panel data and ideally would like to count the number of activities per person.

```
people <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
activity <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,6)
completion <- c(0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1)
```

So my output would tell me that person 4 has 2 tasks.

```
people 1
frequency activity 2
```

Would i need to group something? Ideally i would like to also visualize this as a histogram.

I have tried this:

```
> ##activity per person  cllw %>% 
> ## Group observations by people   group_by(id_user) %>% 
> ## count activities per person and i am not sure how to create frequencies at all
```

Comment: Do you need to count number of unique `activity` for each `people`. something like this `df %>%
  group_by(people) %>%
  summarise(no_activity = n_distinct(activity))` ? Can you show your expected output?

Comment: @Ronak Shah, i would like to have the output like this: person 4 freq activity 2

Comment: SO is not a code writing website, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Bruno sorry i will update what i have tried it just did not lead anywhere, sorry about that

Comment: @s_t sounds clever, histogram ends up looking unreadable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(people) %>% 
  summarise("frequency activity" = n())

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  people `frequency activity`
   <dbl>                <int>
1      1                    3
2      2                    2
3      3                    2
4      4                    2
5      5                    2
```

Or like this if you only want "active" tasks:

```
df %>% 
  filter(completion != 1) %>% 
  group_by(people) %>% 
  summarise("frequency activity" = n())

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  people `frequency activity`
   <dbl>                <int>
1      1                    2
2      2                    1
3      4                    2
4      5                    1
```

---

Edit for unique tasks per person:

```
df %>% 
  filter(completion != 1) %>% 
  distinct(people, activity) %>% 
  group_by(people) %>%
  summarise("frequency activity" = n())

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  people `frequency activity`
   <dbl>                <int>
1      1                    1
2      2                    1
3      4                    1
4      5                    1
```

Comment: wow, thank you this is such a helpful line of code, that i was somehow unable to create. One question, would it be possible to differentiate between tasks and unique tasks? In this case in the first scenario we would i have one activity for user 1

Comment: i get the error that n is only applicable in data context

Comment: @Domink S. Meier one last question, i get an error message when running this..

Comment: n() should only be called in a data context, could it be that summarise does not know which variable to count since in my original data i have more columns

Comment: replace `summarise` with `dplyr::summarise` (if this doesn't work put `dplyr::` before all other function calls int the pipe as well

Comment: @ 2 last things: 1) how would i create a histogram out of this and how can i print the full output, R just shows me a few rows

Comment: Plot: add this after `summarise`: %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(people), y = "frequency activity")) +
  geom_col(). View whole output: add `%>% View()` after `summarise`

Comment: thank you, i really needed this and i promise this will get a lot of use!